# Unable to fathom Perl hash references

Tags: perl, reference

My Perl project can run on multiple systems, but I don't want them to run in isolation without knowing what other systems are doing. I need to keep their data files more or less in sync, which means merging their contents, so I need a data structure to contain details of each computer together with a reference to another computer which is its peer.

It is this referencing that is causing me problems.

If I simplify it to just two PCs

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Sys::Hostname;

# Peer computers
my $PC1 = {
    name => 'PC1',
    os   => 'Linux',
    data => '/its/data/directory',
    peer => 'PC2' #  But whas is really needed here is a reference to PC2's data structure below
};

my $PC2 = {
    name => 'PC2',
    os   => 'MSWin32',
    data => 'X:\\its\\data\\directory',
    peer => 'PC1' #  But whas is really needed here is a reference to PC1's data structure above
};

my $PEERS = [ $PC1, $PC2 ];

# Some code to set up the peer fields, for example
for my $p ( @$PEERS ) {

    my %Peer = %$p;

    if ( $Peer{name} eq 'PC1' ) {
        $Peer{peer} = $PC2;
    }
    else {
        $Peer{peer} = $PC1;
    }

    %$p = %Peer;    # I was surprised to find this line is necessary, otherwise the changes are lost
}

# Determine which system we are, and which we should pair with by default
for my $p ( @$PEERS ) {

    my %THIS = %$p;
    my %PEER = $THIS{peer};

    if ( ( $THIS{name} eq hostname ) && ( $THIS{os} eq $^O ) ) {
        print( $THIS{name}.', '.$PEER{name}."\n" );
        last;
    }
}
```

This gives the following

> # perl test.pl
>       Reference found where even-sized list expected at test.pl line 43.
>       Reference found where even-sized list expected at test.pl line 43.

How can I achieve setting a reference in the peer field which can be dereferenced later?

Comment: Note: `my %Peer = %$p` will make a copy of the hash, if you instead keep the reference `my $Peer = $p` or simply just use `$p`, and modify the hash value through the reference, you do not need to update the whole hash later. For example, you can do `$p->{peer} = $PC1` instead of copying the whole hash: `%$p = %Peer`. See [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more information about Perl references

Comment: The warning that you get, stems from this line: `my %PEER = $THIS{peer}`. Here `$THIS{peer}` is a hash reference, but the left-hand side of the assignment is not a reference. So you would need `my %PEER = %{ $THIS{peer} }`

Comment: I feel your question might find a better reception here if you remove the first paragraph and change the title to something more technical (and related to the problem). As someone else on this site said: "*A title should attempt to describe the problem, not how you feel*". :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for the inputs, and apologies for not replying sooner.  I've changed the test file accordingly, and it now works, but you may care to note the extra fix to get it to work with Active Perl v5.24.1 on Windows.  Because of this, I thought it better to post another answer to my own question, rather than post a comment or whatever.  The successful test file now reads:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Sys::Hostname;

# Peer computers
my $PC1 =
    {
    name    => 'PC1',
    os      => 'Linux',
    data    => '/its/data/directory',
    peer    => 'PC2' #  But whas is really needed here is a reference to PC2's data structure below
    };

my $PC2 =
    {
    name    => 'PC2',
    os      => 'MSWin32',
    data    => 'X:\\its\\data\\directory',
    peer    => 'PC1' #  But whas is really needed here is a reference to PC1's data structure above
    };

my @PEERS = ( $PC1, $PC2 );

# Some code to set up the peer fields, for example
for my $p ( @PEERS )
    {
    if( $p->{name} eq $PC1->{name} )
        {
        $p->{peer} = $PC2;
        }
    else
        {
        $p->{peer} = $PC1;
        }
    }

# Debug check  -  dump the fields
for my $p ( @PEERS )
    {
    my %This = %{$p};               # Fix needed for MSWin32, not needed for Linux
    for my $f ( sort(keys %This) )
        {
        print( $f.' = '.($f eq 'peer' ? $p->{$f}->{name} : $p->{$f})."\n" );
        }
    print( "\n" );
    }

# Determine which system we are, and which we should pair with by default
for my $p ( @PEERS )
    {
    my $THIS = $p;
    my $PEER = $THIS->{peer};
    if( ($THIS->{name} eq hostname) && (lc($THIS->{os}) eq lc($^O)) )
        {
        print( $THIS->{name}.', '.$PEER->{name}."\n" );
        last;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want a good introduction to references in Perl, I recommend [`perldoc perlreftut`](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut). From the languages you listed, C and its pointers are closest to Perl's references (except that there is no "reference arithmetic" or invalid references). In particular, dereferencing is an explicit operation in Perl.

You're trying to construct a cyclic structure: `$PC1` contains a reference to `$PC2`, and `$PC2` contains a reference to `$PC1`. I recommend against doing so because Perl's automatic memory management is based on reference counting. If you create a reference cycle, it will not be freed automatically until you manually break the cycle. (You can work around this by judicious use of [weak references](https://perldoc.pl/Scalar::Util#weaken), but it requires some thought about which references should "own" the structure and which references shouldn't.)

The easiest way to implement this might be to keep your data structures as they are but put them in a hash:

```
my %PEERS = (
    PC1 => {
        name    => 'PC1',
        os      => 'Linux',
        data    => '/its/data/directory',
        peer    => 'PC2',
    },
    PC2 => {
        name    => 'PC2',
        os      => 'MSWin32',
        data    => 'X:\\its\\data\\directory',
        peer    => 'PC1',
    },
);
```

Then you can write code like:

```
for my $name (sort keys %PEERS) {
    my $THIS = $PEERS{$name};
    my $PEER = $PEERS{$THIS->{peer}};
    if ($THIS->{name} eq hostname && $THIS->{os} eq $^O) {
        print $THIS->{name} . ', ' . $PEER->{name} . "\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

Of course, you're now effectively storing the name twice (once as a hash key, once as a field in the (sub-)hash), so you might prefer to change things to:

```
my %PEERS = (
    PC1 => {
        os      => 'Linux',
        data    => '/its/data/directory',
        peer    => 'PC2',
    },
    PC2 => {
        os      => 'MSWin32',
        data    => 'X:\\its\\data\\directory',
        peer    => 'PC1',
    },
);

if (my $THIS = $PEERS{hostname()}) {
    if ($THIS->{os} eq $^O) {
        print "$THIS->{name}, $THIS->{peer}\n";
    }
}
```

This saves us a loop because we can directly look up peers by their hostname.
This assumes your peer names are unique, of course.

---

That said, you can get your original attempt to work, if you really want:

```
# my $PEERS = [ $PC1, $PC2 ];
# I'm not sure why you're using a reference to an array here.
# I'd just use an array, which saves us some dereferencing below:
my @PEERS = ($PC1, $PC2);

for my $Peer ( @PEERS ) {
    # my %Peer = %$p;
    # This line makes a copy of the %$p hash.
    # We want to modify %$p directly, so let's not do that.

    if ($Peer->{name} eq 'PC1') {
        $Peer->{peer} = $PC2;
    }
    else {
        $Peer->{peer} = $PC1;
    }
    # %$p = %Peer;    # I was surprised to find this line is necessary, otherwise the changes are lost
    # We don't need to copy the modified hash back because now we're modifying %$p directly.
}
```

Similarly,

```
for my $p ( @$PEERS ) {
    my %THIS = %$p;
    my %PEER = $THIS{peer};
```

should become

```
for my $THIS ( @PEERS ) {
    my $PEER = $THIS->{peer};
```

There's no need to copy `%$p` into `%THIS`, and you're getting warnings because you're assigning `$THIS{peer}` (a reference) to `%PEER` (a hash). If you really wanted to make a copy here, you'd have to use `%PEER = %{ $THIS->{peer} }` (dereference the reference, as with `%{ $p }` (which was shortened to `%$p` in the original code)).

Answer (score 1):

You have two different issues here.

Firstly, the complexity for your code for setting the `peer` value in your hashes. Your code works, but I think we can make it a lot simpler if a) we stop storing PC details in individual scalars and b) we stop creating unnecessary dereferenced copies of hashes.

```
my $PCs = {
  PC1 => {
    name    => 'PC1',
    os      => 'Linux',
    data    => '/its/data/directory',
    peer    => 'PC2',
  },
  PC2 => {
    name    => 'PC2',
    os      => 'MSWin32',
    data    => 'X:\\its\\data\\directory',
    peer    => 'PC1',
  },
};
```

We can then wire up the `peer` values with code like this:

```
for (values %$PCs) {
  if (exists $PCs->{$_->{peer}) {
    $_->{peer} = $PCs->{$_->{peer}};
  } else {
    warn "PC $_->{name} has an unknown peer: $_->{peer}\n";
  }
}
```

But that's just a cleaner way of writing your existing code. The PCs end up wired together in exactly the same way.

Then there's your error message. That's not caused by your data structures at all. It's caused by this line:

```
my %PEER = $THIS{peer};
```

You're trying to initialise a hash with a hash reference. And that's not going to work; you need to dereference the hash.

```
my %PEER = %{ $THIS{peer} };
```

But we don't really need that `%PEER` variable at all (or `%THIS`).

```
for my $p ( values %$PCs ) {
  if ( ($p->{name} eq hostname) && ($p->{os} eq $^O) ) {
    print "$p->{name}, $p->{peer}{name}\n";
    last;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this would benefit from using a named loop control variable `$pc` in your first `for` loop, as you do in the second.